# Ubuntu lenovo yoga touch screen not working

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen

I'm very new to Linux/Ubuntu. I have a Lenovo Yoga where I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1, everything is fine but the Touchscreen doesn't work.
I was reading a bit how to do it but is very confusing, some source said i should install something to make it work, others says in new laptop it should work out of the box if calibration is adjusted.
Can someone give me direction?

I was reading this but there is no date so I'm not sure if  outdated info:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

Comment: There is no guarantee that each and every touchscreen is supported by Linux. Run `xinput` find out the touchscreen model and search for a solution if one exists.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. I ran `xinput` and I don't see any touchscreen input at all 0.0
Is this normal? I found some people online having positive experience with Linux Mint and Lenovo C640 so I tried to install it too but I didn't have the same luck :(

Comment: Try Ubuntu 20.10 from a LiveUSB. There is a chance it got support. Same laptop models can have different devices.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try :)

Comment: any luck with your device?