# Ubuntu on lenovo yoga: touchscreen and audio issues

Tags: drivers, lenovo, touchscreen

I bought a Lenovo yoga 7i and I initially installed  Ubuntu 20.04.1, but some components did not work.

Searching online and reading the answers to this question:

[ubuntu lenovo yoga touch screen not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299507/ubuntu-lenovo-yoga-touch-screen-not-working/1300301#1300301)

I installed the 20.10 version, gaining touchpad and brightness control, while audio (only speakers) and touchscreen still remained not working. Have you got some suggestions to enable them?

Answer (score 1):

its a bug that wont be fixed because of its low priority: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1876991

i just ended up switching to elementary os